# terminate socket connection on refresh or reload nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a node.js application subscribed to a channel listening for an event. When it hears that event it publishes another event to a new channel. I have been using MubSub for my publish/subscriptions. My issue is that no matter what I do every time the page is reloaded there are two listeners and two publishes, then 3,4,5,6 etc..

I dont understand why they do not get disconnected?

```
if (curURL == '/handwash') {

    db2.handwash.find({
        "event": "handwash"
    }).sort({
        "message.time": -1
    }).limit(10).forEach(function(error, x) {
        if (error || !x) {
            console.log("error getting items");
        } else {
            socket.emit('archive', x.message);
        }
    });


    channel2.subscribe('dealer out', function(message) {

        console.log("new dealer event " + message);
        db.events.find({
            "event": "wash"
        }).sort({
            "message.time": -1
        }).limit(1).forEach(function(error, x) {
            if (error || !x) {
                console.log("error getting items");
            } else {
                console.log("found last handwash..." + x.message.type + "....publishing");

                var message = ({

                        'tableid': 123,
                        'time': Date(),
                        'type': x.message.type,

                })

                channel.publish('handwash', message );

                socket.emit('message', message);
            }
        });


        //socket.emit('message', message);

    });

    socket.on("disconnect", function(s) {
        console.log("Disconnected from global handler");
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using MubSub for subscription and publishing messages. Fixed it by creating a varaible for my connection and then closing it with a unsubscribe();

```
var subscription = channelEvents.subscribe('pocket', function(message) {}
subscription.unsubscribe();
```